# using directives for Unity scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any harm (e.g. performance issues) in including all the directives that might be useful?

For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEngine.VR;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it just tells compiler to look for this namespace prefix of every type it can not resolve.

Comment: oh I see... So, it is **only** consulted when the compiler comes across a type it cannot resolve?

Comment: Yes. No runtime operations are performed for this directives.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will sort out whats not needed but I tend to remove unused usings as a matter of good practice (I find it makes my code that tiny bit shorter).

Essentially this comes down to 2 things ...

1. Usings you need in order to get the code to compile
2. Personal preference

Comment: I fully understand now. Many thanks to both of you guys.